# Groups of units $U(n)$ and their non-subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $U(n)$ be the multiplicative group of $k$ that are coprime to $n$.

Let $U_k(n) = \{x \in U(n) \mid x \mod k = 1\}$.

I proved that if $k>0$ divides $n$ then $U_k (n)$ is a subgroup of $U(n)$. This lead me to thinking about for which $k$ and why $U_k (n)$ fails to be a subgroup of $U(n)$.

My thoughts:

Since $x \in U(n)$ are all $<n$ we only need to consider $k < n$. The $k>0$ that do not divide $n$ are all coprime to $n$. Hence we consider $U_k(n)$ for $k \in U(n)$.

One case for which $U_k (n)$ might fail is when $ab \mod k = 0$ for some $a,b \in U_k (n)$ that is, in  $U_k (n)$ we might have zero divisors if $k$ does not divide $n$.

But it's not so clear to me why this happens and also, there are probably other things that can go wrong like for example an element not having an inverse.

So my question is:

> What is the full explanation (covering all cases) in which $U_k (n)$ fails
>   to be a subgroup of $U(n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the main thing is that if $k\not\mid n$ then the set
$$U_k(n) = \{x \in U(n) \mid x \bmod k = 1\}$$
does not really make sense.  For example, take $n=10$ and $k=3$.  Now I guess you could say that $U(10)$ consists of the integers $1,3,7,9$, and of these $1,7$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $3$, so $U_k(n)=\{1,7\}$.

However, the elements of $U(n)$ are not "really" integers, they are congruence classes, in this case modulo $10$.  So we could just as well write $19$ instead of $9$ to get
$$U(n)=\{1,3,7,19\}\ ,$$
and then you would have
$$U_k(n)=\{1,7,19\}\ ,\quad\hbox{that is,}\quad U_k(n)=\{1,7,9\}\ .$$
Or we could write
$$U(n)=\{11,17,23,29\}$$
in which case $U_k(n)=\varnothing$.

What it comes down to is that if the value of $m$ is only defined up to modulo $10$, then the question "is $m\equiv1\pmod3$?" does not have an unambiguous answer.

Note that the problem does not arise if $k\mid n$.  For example, take $n=10$ and $k=5$.  Then for any $m$ we have
$$5\mid m\quad\hbox{iff}\quad 5\mid m+10t\ ,$$
and so there is no ambiguity as to whether or not $m\equiv1\pmod5$.

**Comment**.  BTW your remark "the $k>0$ that do not divide $n$ are all coprime to $n$" is not correct, for example, $n=10$ and $k=6$.

Comment: Thank you, especially for your comment at the end. Rethinking my wrong statement after reading your answer would the following be a correct observation: If $k$ and $n$ are coprime then $n \mod k$ can be any number in $\{0, \dots, k-1\}$ and this is why $U_k (n)$ is not well-defined in this case. In the other case, where $k$ does not divide $n$, $n \mod k$ can be any number in $\{0, \dots , gcd(n,k)-1\}$?

Comment: The value of $n$ modulo $k$ will always be a multiple of $\gcd(n,k)$.  This means that your first statement is correct but not your second.

Comment: Thank you. So what values can be achieved in the second case? It seems to me that the answer should be different to the first case since $n$ and $k$ share a factor. If I concretely calculate the example with $n=10$ and $k=6$ it seems that $[9 + 10j] \mod 6 = \{3, 1, 5\}$ but it's not clear to me how these numbers relate to $x + n\cdot j \mod k$. Is there any relation at all?

Comment: I'm not quite clear now what your question is.  But the values of $9+10j$ modulo $6$ are just $9+gt$ where $g=\gcd(6,10)=2$.  This gives $9,11,13,15,\ldots$, also $7,5,3,\ldots$ because $t$ could be negative, and modulo $6$ these numbers are just $1,3,5$ repeated lots and lots of times.

Comment: I was trying to understand what can go wrong if $k$ does not divide $n$ but if $k$ and $n$ have common factors. I think that if $k$ and $n$ are not coprime but share some factors and $k$ does not divide $n$ then for $x \in U(n)$  and $y\in \mathbb Z$ the expression $$ x + n\cdot y (\mod k)$$ yields any number  in $\{0, \dots, k-1\}$. (continued)

Comment: So it doesn't seem to matter whether $n$ and $k$ are coprime of not: as long as $k$ does not divide $n$ the set $[x] = \{ x \in U(n) \mid x \mod k \}$ equals $\{0, \dots, k-1\}$ because the expression $x + ny \mod k$ can attain all these values.

Comment: I incorrectly thought that the set $[x]$ depends on whether $n$ and $k$ are coprime or not (in the case where $k$ does not divide $n$). Am I making any sense?

Comment: Apologies for not replying earlier, I have been offline for a few days.  I believe that everything you are asking is covered by the following.  Let $k$ and $n$ be integers and write $g=\gcd(k,n)$.  If $x$ is a fixed integer and $y$ is any integer, then the expression $x+ny\bmod k$ yields all of those numbers $x+mg$ (within the range $0$ to $k-1$) such that $m$ is an integer, and no others.  In particular, it does not yield all integers fro $0$ to $k-1$, except in the case $g=1$.